# Does ${\rm Res}_{z=z_0}\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}=\frac{p(z_0)}{q^{(m)}(z_0)}$ for all $m\ge 1?$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

*I know the following result involving pole*:

> If $p(z),q(z)$ be two functions analytic at $z=z_0$ and $p(z_0)\ne0$ and $q(z)$ has a zero of order $m$ at $z_0$ (i.e. $q(z)=(z-z_0)^mf(z)$ where $f(z)$ is analytic and nonzero at $z_0$) then $\dfrac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z_0.$

Now if $m=1$ then ${\rm Res}_{z=z_0}\dfrac{p(z)}{q(z)}=\dfrac{p(z_0)}{q'(z_0)}.$

Can this result be generalized for $m>1$ i.e. whether ${\rm Res}_{z=z_0}\dfrac{p(z)}{q(z)}=\dfrac{p(z_0)}{q^{(m)}(z_0)}$ for all $m\ge 1?$

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As to the content of your question, what if $q^{(m)}(z_0) \ne q'(z_0)$? Is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: It's more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assertion is false. By Cauchy's formula, for any closed curve $\gamma$ around $z_0$,

$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{p(z)/f(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}dz=\left. \frac{d^{m-1}p(z)/f(z)}{dz}\right|_{z=z_0}$.

In particular if $m=1$, you get $\frac{p(z_0)}{f(z_0)}$ which also happens to be the right answer when calculating the Residue via limit for a simple pole: $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}(z-z_0)\left[\frac{p(z)}{(z-z_0)f(z)}\right]=\frac{p(z_0)}{f(z_0)}$. Notice that $q'(z)=f(z)+(z-z_0)f'(z)$ , so $q'(z_0)=f(z_0)$ but this falls apart for $m>1$ since you have to evaluate $m$ derivatives of $p(z)/f(z)$ which is more complicated.